# Summing a row excluding its minimum value

Tags: matlab

I need some help please.
Let's say I have a matrix:

```
   4 5 6 6
a= 2 7 9 1
   9 0 4 5
```

I want to find the sum of row 2, without including the minimum value of row 2 (that's 1),
I have tried this:

```
sum(a(2,:)~=1)
```

but it does not work.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this without indexing is to subtract the minimum off of the sum,

```
sum(a(2, :)) - min(a(2, :))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
sum(a(2,:)~=1)
```

tells you *how many* entries in the second row are not the minimum of 1. That's because the argument to `sum`,

```
>> a(2,:)~=1
ans = 
     1     1     1     0
```

is a logical array that indicates whether each of the numbers in that row is different from 1, and the logical values false and true are interpreted as numbers 0 and 1 by `sum`.

What you want to do is use these values for *logical indexing* into the row, and summing only the selected elements

```
ind = a(2,:)~=1;
sum(a(2,ind))
```

or shorter

```
sum(a(2,a(2,:)~=1))
```

Of course for generality it would be better to replace `1` by the expression `min(a(2,:))`